# glUniform vs. single draw call performance

Tags: opengl, opengl-es

Suppose I have many meshes I'd like to render. I have two choices:

1. Bake transforms and colors for each mesh into a VBO and render with a single draw call.
2. Use glUniform for transforms and colors and use many draw calls (but still a single VBO)

Assuming the scene changes very little between frames, which method tends to be better?

Comment: Short answer: go for option 1. It kinda depends on the situation, but most of the time, option 1 is going to give you better performance.

Comment: It sounds like what you are after is actually instancing. You can index a UBO using `gl_InstanceID` and do this all in a single draw call, or if you have few enough parameters you can use an attribute divisor. I am not sure why you are drawing one primitive at a time though? Particles?

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman - I assumed in my answer that "...for each primitive" didn't mean that those attributes varied for each primitive (i.e. triangle), but varied by groups of primitives (so the question is really about how hard you should try to merge meshes to avoid too many draw calls). Perhaps Taylor could clarify.

Comment: I don't think I can use instancing. Each primitive is a mesh that can be totally different. I will update the question :)

Comment: Yes, I thought about instancing, but the question did not suggest that the geometry was repetitive. Since there's an `opengl-es` tag, it's also worth mentioning that instanced drawing is an ES 3.0 feature.

Comment: Instanced drawing is available in ES 2.0 on some platforms — check for the `GL_EXT_draw_instanced`  extension.

Answer (score 2):

There are more than those two choices. At least one more comes to mind:

1. ...
2. ....
3. Use attributes for transforms and colors and use many draw calls.

Choice 3 is similar to choice 2, but setting attributes (using calls like `glVertexAttrib4f`) is mostly faster than setting uniforms. The efficiency of setting uniforms is highly platform dependent. But they're generally not intended to be modified very frequently. They are called **uniform** for a reason. :)

That being said, choice 1 might be the best for your use case where the transforms/colors change rarely. If you're not doing this yet, you could try keeping the attributes that are modified in a separate VBO (with usage `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW`), and the attributes that remain constant in their own VBO (with usage `GL_STATIC_DRAW`). Then make the necessary updates to the dynamic buffer with `glBufferSubData`.

The reality is that there are no simple rules to predict what is going to perform best. It will depend on the size of your data and draw calls, how frequent and large the data changes are, and also very much on the platform you run on. If you want to be confident that you're using the most efficient solution, you need to implement all of them, and start benchmarking.

Comment: I like your option 3! Using many draw calls makes it easier to manage the VBO. Hopefully I'll see a performance improvement by reducing reliance on glUniform.

Comment: It really depends on how many draw calls you have. Just to give you a rough idea, you can typically get throughput of a few million draw calls per second on a desktop/laptop with relatively simple state changes between them. I don't have the numbers for mobile devices, but even if they're an order of magnitude lower, you're looking at a good part of 1 million/second. So if you want to reach 60 fps, 100 draw calls/frame should be no problem at all. 1,000 draws/frame should still be fine. I would start to be worried if you're going more in the range of 10,000 draws/frame.

Comment: Cool. The documents I'm testing require on the order of 1k draw calls/frame.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, option 1 (minimize number of draw calls) is the best advice. There are a couple of caveats:

I have seen performance fall off a cliff when using very large VBOs on at least one mobile device (assuming relevant for opengl-es tag). The explanation (from the vendor) involved  internal buffers exceeding a certain size.

If putting all the information which would otherwise be conveyed with uniforms into vertex attributes significantly increases the size of the vertex buffer, the price you pay (in perhaps costly memory reads) of reading redundant information (because it doesn't really vary per vertex) might negate the savings of using fewer draw calls.

As always the best (but tiresome) advice is to test (I know this is particularly hard developing for mobile where there are many potential implementations your code could be running on). Try to keep your pipeline/toolchain flexible enough that you can easily try out and compare different options.